# Disable Woocommerce products based on their regular price value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, visibility, product

On my Woocommerce website, I have a plugin which sometimes change product price to regular price = null (for different reasons).

When that happens, we'd like to disable the product so it doesn't show in our online store. How can we do this in functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

This code will disable products from catalog and search, when regular price is **`NULL`** and will re-enable the disabled products when regular price is not `NULL` anymore:

```
add_action( 'init', 'action_on_product_reg_price' );
function action_on_product_reg_price(){
    global $wpdb;

    // First query: Get the product Ids that have a NULL regular price
    $product_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT pm.post_id as product_id
        FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm2 ON pm2.post_id = pm.post_id
        WHERE (pm.meta_key = '_regular_price'
        AND (pm.meta_value IS NULL
        OR pm.meta_value LIKE 'null'))
        OR (pm2.meta_key LIKE '_force_visibility'
        AND pm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL)
    " );

    // Disable the products from catalog and search
    if(count($product_ids) > 0){
        foreach($product_ids as $product_id){
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            if($product->get_catalog_visibility() != 'hidden' ) {
                $product->set_catalog_visibility('hidden'); // visible
                $product->save();
                update_post_meta( $product_id, '_force_visibility', 1 );
            }
        }
    }

    // 2nd query: Get the product Ids that have changed from NULL regular price
    $product_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT pm.post_id as product_id
        FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm2 ON pm2.post_id = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '_regular_price'
        AND (pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        OR pm.meta_value NOT LIKE 'null')
        AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_force_visibility'
        AND pm2.meta_value = '1'
    " );

    // Re-enable catolog and search visibility
    if(count($product_ids) > 0){
        foreach($product_ids as $product_id){
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            if($product->get_catalog_visibility() != 'visible' ) {
                $product->set_catalog_visibility('visible'); // visible
                $product->save();
                update_post_meta( $product_id, '_force_visibility', NULL );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works on WooCommerce 3+